# Is Naruto homosexual?

Tags: naruto

I do not watch this anime much, but I always read on sites and blogs that Naruto is gay and passionate about another character, Sasuke.

Is this true?

Comment: Fan fiction is a real thing and has its own reality. You'd be best served actually watching for yourself.

Comment: OP I give you one warning `beware the yaoi/yuri fanfiction` almost every popular series has some sort of homo-erotic fanfiction attached to it. Not that it's a bad thing but it can be kind of strange for someone who is new to the hobby

Comment: This is a good question.Why does it have so many downvotes?

Answer (score 9):

Naruto isn't homosexual as in preferring the same sex since at the end of the series, Naruto marries Hinata and has 2 children, Boruto and Himawari. Sasuke too gets married to Sakura and has a child named Sarada.

However, like any fandom, there is also those who like/love same-sex [shipping](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shipping). Naruto did, however, help fans along that in the third episode of the anime [*"Sasuke and Sakura: Friends or Foes?"*](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sasuke_and_Sakura:_Friends_or_Foes%3F) (which adapts the third chapter of the manga), in which Naruto and Sasuke kiss.

> Naruto and Sasuke argue, and then continue to glare at each other until a boy sitting in front of them accidentally bumps into Naruto causing him to fall forward and accidentally kiss Sasuke, much to everyone's disgust.

[image: In the background, a bunch of them now thirst for Naruto's blood]

This results in Sakura getting pissed off, commenting on how Naruto just stole Sasuke's first kiss which she wanted.

Comment: well other than the fact that he marries hinata, naruto was in love with sakura from the beginning and we know how much he likes his sexy jutsus :).

Answer (score 2):

Naruto is not gay.

You're right when it comes to him being passionate about Sasuke, but that is only because Naruto thinks of Sasuke as his older brother, since he himself has no family and loses someone he could call his family later in the anime. He is passionate about Sasuke because of the bond that he created with him and won't let that bond go no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Naruto considers Sasuke both his best friend and his rival. It is a difficult relationship and he's been known to obsess over Sasuke during the whole anime.

A very good example of such obsession occurs when Sasuke leaves. Naruto literally abandons everything else (including his love for Sakura) for the next few years to train in order to get him back. The fact that whenever he sees a glimpse of him he shouts his name like a maniac doesn't make his obsession less obvious. Even Sakura (deeply in love with Sasuke) gives up on him before Naruto does.

But that has nothing to do with sexual orientation. It's just obsessing over someone, something that is most certainly not unheard-of in anime, where many things are blown out of proportion. Naruto is straight.

Answer (score -2):

People claim that he isn't gay, but they stick their fingers up each other's butts when they do the "One Thousand Years of Death" and he does his "Sexy Jutsu"!

He isn't openly gay, but there are gay sexual moments!

Answer (score -2):

Naruto married and having two children doesn't mean he is not gay.

In a real life, closed people getting married to protect their sexual identity or some of them thought their sexual can changed to heterosexual way. There is no preference sexual because heterosexual is not a choice just the same as homosexual is not a choice either.